# Network No Suitable Device when creating ifcfg-eth1

Tags: networking, centos

I need your help with some strange problem
We are trying to create an ifcfg-eth1 network device on our centos 7 server.

We are using the following information in the ifcfg-eth1 file;

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.101.61
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.100.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

The ifcfg-eth0 work like it should, but when we create the ifcfg-eth1 we get the following error;

```
No suitable device found for this connection.
```

Full output from /var/log/messages

```
    Oct  5 10:38:09 switch-onpremis1 network: ループバックインターフェイスを呼び込み中 [  OK  ]
Oct  5 10:38:09 switch-onpremis1 network: インターフェース enp029f2u1 を活性化中:  [  OK  ]
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: インターフェース eth0 を活性化中:  [  OK  ]
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 NetworkManager[665]: <info>  [1538703490.1107] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="9c92fad9-6ecb-3e6c-eb4d-8a47c6f50c04" name="System eth1" result="fail" reason="No suitable device found for this connection."
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: インターフェース eth1 を活性化中:  エラー: 接続のアクティベーションに失敗: No suitable device found for this connection.
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: [失敗]
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 network: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 systemd: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 systemd: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 systemd: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Oct  5 10:38:10 switch-onpremis1 systemd: network.service failed.
```

What could be the problem of this? 
Has it to do with our network card maybe? 
Or could the problem be somewhere else?

Our settings for ifcfg-eth0 are;

```
TYPE=Ethernet
PROXY_METHOD=static
BROWSER_ONLY=no
BOOTPROTO=static
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE=stable-privacy
NAME=eth0
UUID=f3d98d60-6062-4b70-a14c-7ac4040bd403
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.100.60
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=192.168.100.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
```

Thank you for the suggestions.
Help is really appreciated.

We are already struggling with the same problem for the last three days.

Answer (score 0):

Networking has changed with CentOS 7.x, Checkout the following:

Read `3. And what if I want the old naming back?`

Also, check out `7. What have you done with ifconfig/netstat?`

https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7

Answer (score 0):

I checked:

```
journalctl -u network.service
```

for me it was:

```
Bringing up interface enp2s0f0:  Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device eth0 not available because profile is not compatible with device (permanent MAC address doesn't match)).
```

then go to

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
```

In my case I have I noticed some files like ifcfg-* , I deleted them and have only left ifcg-eth0 - that worked for me

So checking `journalctl -xe` log (`journalctl -u network.service`) helped me figure out the error cause.

The error was due to:

- Wrong DEVICE=eth0
- Existence of some files like ifcfg-*